# How to change the button color of a gridView

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a Gridview displaying buttons that get their content from an array, I would like to change the background color of these buttons when **clicking/pressed** on it. I tried onClick and onTouch, it does go in to the method, but color is not background is not set. What is wrong with my code? Please help.

```
private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

            btnView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("onClick","go");
                    btnView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(12,11,12));
                    btnView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3614B3")); 

                    Intent data = new Intent();
                    data.setData(Uri.parse("PictureStyle" + position));
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);

                 }
             });

            btnView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    Log.d("OnTouch","go2");
                    btnView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3614B3")); 
                    return false;

                 }
             });


            btnView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("Touch listener",String.valueOf(position));
                    btnView.setBackgroundColor(0xff00ff00); 
                    Log.d("Touch listener","set");
                    if ( event.equals(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) ) {
                        btnView.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000); 

                                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: `btnView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);` and why `setOnTouchListener` i think clicking/pressing then set `setOnClickListener`

Comment: I am able to set the background, but not when it is clicked. I am trying to get the background changed when it is pressed and not release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it with `v.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(12,11,12));` in your onClick

Answer (score 0):

You better use `GridView.setOnItemClickListener` instead of register a clickListener on each Button